# Remove comments with ReSharper

Tags: c#, comments, resharper

I have several classes whose members are annotated with the comment `// -----------`:

```
public class Bla
{
    // -----------
    public Bla() {}

    // -----------
    public int GetBla { get; set; }

    // -----------
    public void DoBla() { }
}
```

Does anyone know how to remove this with ReSharper Code Cleanup?

Comment: CRTL+SHIFT+H > `// -----------` : " " (blank space) > Replace All? You could use RegEx, too

Comment: I could do this from time to time, you're right. Since I'm introducing a ReSharper Code Cleanup profile, I'm curious to know whether this could be automated...

Comment: I'm just wondering, why do you have those in the first place? Auto-generated code?

Comment: To be honest: I don't know. I'm trying to introduce a common coding style in a company.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need Resharper for this.

Use find and replace with regex `// -+` and replace all with nothing.

If a certain number of dashes `// -{3,}`

[image]

Comment: I added an image, hope that's what you meant

Answer (score 1):

Based on [this](http://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Coding_Assistance__Comment_Uncomment_Code.html), you can use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> to uncomment in Resharper:

> An alternative way to uncomment any line comment is to set the caret on this line, press Alt+Enter and choose Uncomment.

And if you want to remove all comments with a click of a button, then you need to know that Resharper doesn't have a feature to do this but you can use [CommentRemover](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.CommentRemover) extension for Visual Studio.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I don't understand how this removes the comment.

Comment: @mu88 Just set the caret on this line, press Alt+Enter and choose Uncomment.

Comment: This results in "---------" instead of removing the line. I could invoke "Delete Comment", but how to automate this?

Comment: @mu88 Then you need to use CommentRemover extension for Visual Studio as I have mentioned in my answer because I don't think Resharper could automate this!

Comment: @mu88 The `CommentRemover` is really a cool extension. It can remove all comments in any file with a click of a button based on your setting. Can also remove #regions and preserve XML Doc comments.